# Plotting absorbing state probabilities from state 1

Tags: plotting, markov-chains, markov-process

I have the following transition matrix:

```
\[ScriptCapitalP] = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, {{0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0.5, 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0.5, 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.5, 0.5}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.}}]
```

Visually, it looks as shown at the bottom.

Looking at the graph, I can see the absorbing states easily, and I can calculate individual probabilities of reaching a particular absorbing state from state 1. For example, from state 1 to state 9:

```
PDF[\[ScriptCapitalP][∞], 9]
```

However, this manual process is hardly practical with larger matrices.

So, what I wish to achieve is an automatic computation of all absorbing state probabilities from state 1, so that I can finally plot these.

How might that be achieved?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`MarkovProcessProperties`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MarkovProcessProperties.html)

```
absorbingStateProbs1[p_] := Extract @@ (MarkovProcessProperties[
       p, #] & /@ {"ReachabilityProbability", "AbsorbingClasses"});

absorbingStateProbs1@\[ScriptCapitalP]
```

> {0.125, 0.375, 0.375, 0.125}

Alternatively,

```
absorbingStateProbs2[p_] := PDF[p[∞], #] & /@
  Flatten[MarkovProcessProperties[p, "AbsorbingClasses"]]

absorbingStateProbs2@\[ScriptCapitalP]
```

> {0.125, 0.375, 0.375, 0.125}