# The probability of reaching the absorbing states from a particular transient state?

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

Can I use the data available from MarkovProcessProperties to compute the probability of reaching each of the absorbing states from a particular transient state?

In an earlier [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187101/plotting-absorbing-state-probabilities-from-state-1), kglr showed a solution involving the probabilities from State 1. Can that solution be amended easily to compute the probabilities from any of the transient states?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `StationaryDistribution[DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1,0,0},{{0,1/2,1/2},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}}]]`

Comment: I am looking for a solution like the one shown by kglr in the link, but which is more dynamic because it offers the possibility of specifying the particular transient state to be examined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, {{0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, 
  {0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0., 0.}, 
  {0., 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0.}, 
  {0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, 
  {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0.5, 0., 0.},
  {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0.5, 0.}, 
  {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.}, 
  {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.5, 0.5},
  {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.}, 
  {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.}}];

Graph[proc]
```

[image]

```
{tr, ab, ltm} = MarkovProcessProperties[proc, #] & /@ 
  { "TransientClasses", "AbsorbingClasses", "LimitTransitionMatrix"};

TeXForm @ TableForm[ltm[[Flatten@tr, Flatten@ab]], 
 TableHeadings -> {Flatten@tr, Flatten@ab}]
```

> $\begin{array}{ccccc}
>   & 4 & 7 & 9 & 10 \\
>  3 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0. & 0. \\
>  6 & 0. & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0. \\
>  2 & 0.25 & 0.5 & 0.25 & 0. \\
>  8 & 0. & 0. & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
>  5 & 0. & 0.25 & 0.5 & 0.25 \\
>  1 & 0.125 & 0.375 & 0.375 & 0.125 \\
> \end{array}$

**Update:** *"Suppose I had a very large transition matrix, and I was interested in only one transient state, say 6."*

The 6th row of `ltm` contains the desired probabilities:

```
ltm[[6, Flatten@ab]]
```

> {0., 0.5, 0.5, 0.}

Comment: Suppose I had a very large transition matrix, and I was interested in only one transient state, say 6. How would I go about entering just that number in your code (a newbie question, I know, but I am having a little difficulty seeing where the number 6 goes). But please don't remove your current solution, which is terrific.

Comment: @user120911, if, say, `8` is the transient state you are interested in you can use `ltm[[8, Flatten@ab]`